# "if" or "present?" check possible in Sunspot search or something equivalent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

Is there any way to check for presence(like create and "if" condition within the search) of an object with Sunspot?

I am trying to implement this equivalent search in sunspot:

```
Apartment.where('(title LIKE ? OR street_address LIKE ? OR apartment_number LIKE ? OR city LIKE ? OR state LIKE ?) AND (price >= ? AND price <= ? AND (average_overall_rating >= ? OR average_overall_rating IS ?) AND bedrooms >= ? AND bedrooms <= ? AND bathrooms >= ? AND bathrooms <= ?)',
            "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%",
            min_price.presence || 0, max_price.presence || Apartment.maximum("price"),
            min_rating.presence || 0, min_rating.presence || nil,
            min_bedrooms.presence || 0, max_bedrooms.presence || Apartment.maximum("bedrooms"), 
            min_bathrooms.presence || 0, max_bathrooms.presence || Apartment.maximum("bathrooms")).order(sorting)
```

My search controller method:

```
def search
    @search = Apartment.search do
        fulltext params[:search]
        with(:price).between(min_price.to_f..max_price.to_f)
        with(:average_overall_rating).greater_than_or_equal_to(min_rating.to_f)
        with(:bedrooms).between(min_bedrooms.to_f..max_bedrooms.to_f)
        with(:bathrooms).between(min_bathrooms.to_f..max_bathrooms.to_f)
    end
end
```

I'm trying to only include the "with" statements above when the objects matches a min_price, max_price, or min_rating.

My Searchable block within my model:

```
searchable do
  text :title, :street_address, :apartment_number, :city, :state, :zip

  float :price
  float :bathrooms
  float :bedrooms
  float :average_overall_rating
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can but you must write search method a little bit differently. Try something like this:

```
def search

    @search = Apartment.search do |query|
       query.fulltext params[:search]
       with_price(query)
    end

end

def with_price(query)
   from_price = (min_price.presence || 0).to_f
   to_price = (max_price.presence || Apartment.maximum("price")).to_f
   query.with(:price).between(from_price..to_price)
end
```